# How to keep zero decimal place for zero?

Tags: c#

I used:

```
Result_TextBox.Text = result.ToString(".#######");  //result is double
```

But if the result is 100.0000000, it becomes 100. What should I use in order to keep the accuracy of 7 decimals place?

I tried:

```
Result_TextBox.Text = Math.round(result, 7);  //but this is effective at all, why?
```

Please help

Update: can someone explain "#" and "0"?

Comment: When using hash, it means the number can be omitted. e.g `("00.00")` will force the pre decimal numbers to always be 2 digits. e.g (02.12). `("##.00")`  means if the number isn't present it won't show. e.g (2.12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
Result_TextBox.Text = result.ToString("#.0000000");
```

Comment: can you explain "#" and "0"?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Result_TextBox.Text = result.ToString("0.0000000");
```

The second line doesn't work because you're trying to assign a numeric data type to a string without conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result.ToString("0.0000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for that.
You can use [The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier) followed by a number to define the number of decimal digits.

```
Console.WriteLine(100.ToString("F7"));
// -> 100.0000000

Console.WriteLine(100.ToString("F3"));
// -> 100.000
```

Example : https://dotnetfiddle.net/EmPewm